# Cannot update node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to update node.js in order to scaffold an angular project.

But when I launch this command:

```
npm update -g
```

I am getting this:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "update" "-g"
npm ERR! node v5.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/vs-tac
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 'vs-tac' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Development\workspaceWeb\redPlus\npm-debug.log
```

I decided to update the npm because I was getting other errors when calling

```
yo angular --minsafe
```

so I split the involved programs.

How to fix it?

Comment: it seems like you have a packege which dose not exist on npm anymore. could you add a pastebin/fiddle of the result of running `npm ls -g --depth=0`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5aXRfxZ0

Comment: So it seems the answers here are correct. This is an unpublished package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a package linked to cordova, you can manually reinstall it: http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-vs-tools-apache-cordova/#vstac You'll need to install Visual Studio though.

Comment: I am not using cordova for this

Answer (score 0):

I think the vs-tac package has been unpublished. You should contact the person who maintains the packages to look further in the issue.